# Obtener valor de un input

Tags: javascript, jquery, entrada

me gustaria saber como mostrar el valor del input en un alert, inmediatamente en el momento que acabe de escribir dentro el input que me lo muestre. En JQuery

```js
function mostrar(num) {
 var x = $("#num").val();
 alert(x);
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" name="num" step="1" Onchange = "mostrar('num')" value=""  size="20"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: parece como si buscaras databinding como el que hay en angular o react jejeje Jquery no está pensado para esto

Answer (score 1):

Bueno creo que hay conceptos mezclados y algunos errores en el ejemplo tanto de marcado html como de jquery, así que lo he editado. Aún así siguiendo literalmente tus instrucciones.

```js
function mostrar() {
 var x = $("#numero").val();
 alert(x);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="1" onkeyup="mostrar()" id="numero" size="20"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Llega a resultar molesto no ? podrías indicar si hace falta algún timeout o esperar a que se produzca algún evento en concreto como onBlur, onChange ...

** Actualizacion **

siendo tu ejemplo el siguiente:

```js
function mostrar(num) {
 var x = $("#num").val();
 alert(x);
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" name="num" step="1" Onchange = "mostrar('num')" value=""  size="20"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

siguen habiendo errores en tu código, aun asi:

```js
function mostrar(input) {
 //solo queremos mostrar la alerta
 // si tengo un formato en concreto
 // por ejemplo dos numeros separados por un espacio
 if(/[0-9]+ [0-9]+/.test(input.value)){
   var numeros = input.value.split(' ');
   alert(numeros[0]+','+numeros[1]);
 }
 //o con jquery usando this
 if(/[0-9]+ [0-9]+/.test($(input).val())){
   var numeros = $(input).val().split(' ');
   alert(numeros[0]+','+numeros[1]);
 }
}
```

```html
<p>
onchange se ejecuta al perder el focus o al cambiar de valor solo en campos select, radio y checkbox <br>
<input type="text"  onchange="mostrar(this)"/>
</p>

<p>
onkeyup se ejecuta justo despues de cada introduccion o eliminacion de caracteres <br>
<input type="text"  onkeyup="mostrar(this)"/>
</p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bueno lo que quiero hacer es que con el valor que le pongo por input, me indique que si es mayor o igual a otro numero. Por lo tanto el evento onkeyup no me sirve. Porque si tengo que escribir dos numeros en el mismo input me entrara dos veces a la funcion.

Comment: Vamos por partes jejej, si lo que deseas es validar dos datos introducidos en el mismo input deberias actualizar correctamente el titulo y contenido de la pregunta, asi podemos ayudarte mejor ;).
Por otro lado describe el proceso que se debe tomar desde el punto de vista de un usuario y que has intentado hasta ahora para conseguirlo.
Si te cuesta descrbirlo usa algun codigo o imagen como ayuda. Ya que sigo sin entender eso del mismo input para dos numeros.

Comment: Oriol me pongo a ello pero actualiza esta informacion en la propia pregunta usando el editor de codigo por favor.

Comment: Ya esta editado Angel!

Comment: @Oriol , te he respondido pero no has descrito correctamente tu caso. Poca gente le hará caso a tus preguntas si no están correctamente descritas. Me comentabas lo de los números y no lo has descrito todavia

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente forma, aprovechando la librería jQuery.

```js
$('#num').focusout(function() {
 var x = $(this).val();
 alert(x);

 // Recomiendo usar la consola en lugar de alerts
 console.log(x);
});
```

```html
    <input type="text" name="num" step="1" id="num" value=""  size="20"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basándome en el código subido lo único que te faltaría es ponerle un id al input ya que estas referenciando un id que no existe por eso muestra undefined.

```js
function mostrar(num) {
         var x = $("#num").val();
         alert(x);
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num" step="1" Onchange = "mostrar('num')" value=""  size="20"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes lograr únicamente con javascript teniendo en cuenta:

- [onkeyup HTML event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp): evento que se dispara cuando se "suelta" una tecla, momento donde te interesa obtener el valor del input.
- [DOM addEventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp): posibilidad de bindear eventos a elementos del DOM

```js
let num = document.getElementById('num'); 
num.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  alert(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num" name="num" step="1"  value=""  size="20"/>
```

Con jQuery:

```js
$('#num').on("keyup", function(){
 alert(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num" name="num" step="1"  value=""  size="20"/>
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```