# Como obtener el valor de una variable almacenada en un input o texto

Tags: javascript, html

Hola soy nuevo en esto y necesito una mano, como puedo obtener el valor de una variable en un input o texto uso HTML Y JAVASCRIPT. En simples palabras lo que quiero hacer es que un input muestre el valor almacenado de una variable

---

[image: este es mi codigo]

[image]

este es mi codigo
y aca muestra el resultado en una alerta, lo que quiero hacer es mostrar en un input o taxto

Comment: De acuerdo, sugiero que describas un poco más el escenario para ir más directamente. El valor de la variable se puede mostrar como resultado de una operación del usuario por ejemplo, ¿cuál sería la que te interesa? ¿O es cuando se carga la página? otro?

Comment: Buenas, esto es algo bastante sencillo y común, ¿has probado a buscar otras preguntas antes de realizar la tuya? Quizá esta te ayude: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/113229/111983

Comment: Hola, cual es el input? Qué es lo que has intentado? Porqué no pones un ejemplo o minímo el código de lo que tiene ahorita para poder ayudarte?

Comment: var A = document.getElementById("location-4").value;
      var B = document.getElementById("location-3").value;
      var C = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text
      var D = A +'*'+ B +'*'+ C;
      alert(D);
      
Bien, te explico este es mi codigo lo que guardo en cada variable son direcciones de calles, lo que quiero hacer es poder mostrar en un input o texto lo que hay dentro  de la variable D, como se podra ver la variable D muestra el contenido de todos los datos que quiero pasar en una alerta, pero lo que quiero hacer es mostrar en un input o texto

Comment: te imaginas que respondamos con imagenes??? de que serviria stackoverflow si todas las preguntas/respuestas sean imagenes

Comment: disculpa nose como pasarte el codigo xq me sale todo  en el texto, soy nuevo en esta comunidad por eso tengo estas dificultades

Comment: por eso no hay problema pega el codigo, si se ve mal otros usuarios adaptaran la pregunta, trata de que sea lo mas entendible para todo, te invito a hacer el [tour] y ver como [ask]

Answer (score 2):

te arme un código con lo que entendí que necesitabas
Si quieres mostrar por pantalla solo tenes que crear otro elemento como `<p>` o un `<span>` o `<div>` y asignarle el valor de tu variable D al elemento con el atributo **textContent** o **innerHTML**.

Como en el siguiente ejemplo.

```js
let variable1 = "Locacion  1";

// O podes usar var 
var variable2 = "Locacion  2";


document.getElementById("location-1").value = variable1;
document.getElementById("location-2").value = variable2;

document.getElementById("info").textContent = `${variable1} - ${variable2}`;
```

```html
  <input placeholder="Location1" type="text" id="location-1" name="location-1" value/>

  <input placeholder="Location2" type="text" id="location-2" name="location-2" value/>

<br/>
<p>
  Las localidades son: 
  <span id="info"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: GRACIAS MIL GRACIAS VOY A PROBAR MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!!!!

Comment: Siiiiiii Gracias funciono perfecto, esto es lo que buscaba muchisimas gracias. MUCHAS MUCHAS GRACIAS !!! :D

Comment: [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)